# Snowflake create procedure - Syntax error: unexpected 'return'

Tags: stored-procedures

I wanted to do an example of a procedure in snowflake but I keep getting this error :

```
Syntax error: unexpected 'return'. (line 2)
```

I don't know what I missing :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TASKEXAMPLE_PROCEDURE()
    RETURNS int
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS 
    $$
    return SELECT UNIFORM(1, 10, random()) as nb from table(generator(rowcount => 1)) ;
    $$;
```

Thank for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use **return** in a stored procedure in Snowflake scripting you need to use blocks, as documented [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/blocks.html).

Here is an example of using **return**:

```
create or replace procedure area()
returns float
language sql
as
$$
declare
    radius float;
    area_of_circle float;
begin
    radius := 3;
    area_of_circle := pi() * radius * radius;
    return area_of_circle;
end;
$$
;
```

Comment: Thank a lot, it's working but without the $$ statements